# why is a new head created during this push?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

My production code is in the `default` branch, new features go into named branches which get merged with `default` when the new features are OK. I recently merged a development `daytemp` into `default` and started to work on the branch `separate processes`. I pushed what I had to bitbucket, this is the status it shows now:

[image: bitbucket]

I realized there was a bug in `default` so, at another computer, I pulled, updated to `default` and fixed the bug. I commited to commit `a7cf17ca158e` (*"bug: all bars were displayed..."*) and wanted to push to bitbucket. This is what Tortoise HG on that computer shows:

[image: Tortoise HG]

Can you please help me to understand where the problem is? From the [mercurial docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial) I understand that I have a fairly standard situation (I have two heads, one for `default` and one for `separate processes`) so I do not understand which new one bitbucket warns me I would be creating when pushing.

**EDIT** it turned out that, following [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870953/vince)'s comment, there indeed was a new head hidden down the graph.

Output `hg outgoing`:

```
changeset:   152:ce343f208e48
parent:      150:ebd10baed373
user:        wojtek
date:        Thu May 15 06:21:43 2014 +0200
summary:     bug: time string when no connection

changeset:   161:a7cf17ca158e
tag:         tip
parent:      159:dd4af8e3f7d5
user:        wojtek
date:        Fri May 16 19:55:54 2014 +0200
summary:     bug: all bars were displayed after a day (not cleaned up)
```

Than changeset `152` was the culprit. After merging it with the current `default` the push went fine.

Comment: Have you tried pulling instead, and seeing if you get two heads in your local repository?

Comment: Yes, I tried. There are no changes. I am the only one working on the code so there could not be any changes without me knowing. But yes, I did try.

Comment: What do you have when doing an `hg outgoing`? Could you have another `default` head in your current repo, not visible in that scope, but attempted to be pushed as well? What I'm saying is the 2 heads may already be in your local repo.

Comment: @Vince I added the output of `hg outgoing` to my question. There is no other `default` head.

Comment: @Vince: you were right. There IS a new head for `default` hidden down the graph. Can you please copy your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Glad you found it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have when doing an `hg outgoing`?

Could you have another `default` head in your current repo, not visible in that scope, but attempted to be pushed as well? What I'm saying is the 2 heads may already be in your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

- As noted in `hg help push`

> By default, push will not allow creation of new heads at the destination,
>   since multiple heads would make it unclear which head to use.

and

> Use `--new-branch` if you want to allow push to create a new named branch that is not present at the destination.

- It's irrelevant (for Mercurial) are these new heads in single branch or in different, they are anyway additional heads
- Default push-settings in TortoiseHG's Workbench doesn't have checkbox'ed "new-branch" option for any repository. Just enable it before pushing changes, which contain changeset in not-existing before on remote repository branch "separate process". Just enable new-branch using before first push of any new branch

[image: Push Options]

Comment: I do not think this is the problem. The remote ranch already exists in bitbucket, I was asked by Tortoise HG whether I wanted to create it remotely or not when I pushed it for the first time (from the first computer).